# QML AnimatedImage uses a lot of memory

Tags: qt, qml, pyside, animated-gif, pyside6

I want to display a simple gif using qml (pyside backend), but it uses almost 100-400 mb of memory. Can I display a gif without using this much memory?

Something like telegram Animated images: https://telegram.org/blog/animated-stickers. The size of telegram animated images are six times smaller than the average photo.

Code:

```
AnimatedImage
{
    width: 37
    height: 28
    scale: 0.7
    source: "Icons/gifIcon.gif"
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: parent.top
    transform: Translate {x: 17; y: 2}
    z: 10
}
```

Comment: How *exactly* are you measuring the memory usage? Please provide a proper [mre], and also give details of the platform you are testing on and the ***specific*** versions of Qt6 and PySide6 you are using.

Comment: thanks for your answer i measure memory usage by task manager and any gif that i add uses 100-400 mb of memory on Windows 10 and i'm using pyside 6 in visual studio code

Comment: Presumably you mean the total memory usage *increases* by 100-400 mb. Anyway, it looks like this may be due to a bug in Qt: see for example [QTBUG-55808](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55808).

Comment: thanks for answer. so what should i do? is there any way to display a gif? with any other languages?

Comment: Well, you *can* display a gif - it just uses a lot of memory. Adding `cache: false` might[?!] be an improvement. The key factor is the number of frames in the gif. Lots of frames means very high memory consumption.

Comment: ok thank you, i use cache: false and now size of gif is 7 mb and is too better thank you (: